# C# passing values from one method to another

Tags: c#, static-methods

I am getting an error code in the result. code below. I am basically trying to get a data set from `SingleColumn` method and use it in `SMA` method. But I am getting results deos not exist in current context.

```
static public void SMA()
{
    double[] closePrice = results.ToArray();
```

Below you can see the `SingleColumn` and part of `SMA` code.

```
#region Single Column
//static public double results;
static public void SingleColumn(IEnumerable<string> strs, int highNum)
{
    #region spilt data to columns
    Console.WriteLine("Single Column Query:");
    var columnQuery = from line in strs 
                      let elements = line.Split(',')
                      select Convert.ToDouble(elements[highNum]); 
    var results = columnQuery.ToList();
    double[] closePrice = results.ToArray();
    #endregion

    #region max, min, avg
    double average = results.Average();
    double max = results.Max();
    double min = results.Min();
    Console.WriteLine("High: {0}: Low: {1}: Average: {2:0.00}", max, min, average);
    #endregion
}

    #region Strategy Code SMA
static public void SMA()
{
    double[] closePrice = results.ToArray(); 
    int TOTAL_PERIODS = closePrice.Length;
    double[] output = new double[TOTAL_PERIODS];
    int begin;
    int length;

    for (int i = 0; i < closePrice.Length-TOTAL_PERIODS; i++) //had to change from -1 to -TOTAL_PERIODS
    {
        closePrice[i] = (double)i;
    }

    TicTacTec.TA.Library.Core.RetCode retCode = Core.Sma(0, closePrice.Length-1, closePrice, PERIODS_AVERAGE, out begin, out length, output);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some options:

1. have `SingleColumn` *return* `results` and add that as a parameter to `SMA`
2. make `results` a field of the class so it is shared.

Option 1. is cleaner since it forces callers to call `SingleColumn` first (or come up with a list on their own)

```
    static public double[] SingleColumn(IEnumerable<string> strs, int highNum)
    {
        ...
        return closePrice;
    }

        #region Strategy Code SMA
    static public void SMA(double[] closePrice)
    {
        int TOTAL_PERIODS = closePrice.Length;
        double[] output = new double[TOTAL_PERIODS];
        ...
    }
```

Note that I changed your output/input from `result` to `closePrice` since it was just converting it to a List and back.  It's cleaner just to leave it as a `double[]`.  You can also clean up the code a bit by just using `ToArray` instead of using `ToList` and *then* `ToArray`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Seems to work and I can compile. This might be  a stupid question, but how do I actually reach the SMA code and it? can you provide me with a quick example.

Comment: What do you mean "reach"  They're static methods, so you call them with the class name in front:  `{classname}.SMA()`.

Comment: @D Stanley when trying to call SMA from the GetHigh method, I am getting "No overload for method 'SMA' takes 0 arguments. I called it by writing SMA();

Comment: I got it :) Program.SMA(SingleColumn(lines, high + 1)); Thanks for to all who assisted me int his matter!

Answer (score 0):

You should use static variable.

```
private static IEnumerable<double> result;
```

and then in method SingleColumn asign columnQuery.ToList() to this variable

Answer (score 0):

Each variable in C# is exists within a scope which is defined by curly braces. In your case the variable result is within the scope SingleCloumn.

```
public static void SingleColumn(IEnumerable<string> strs, int highNum)
{

}
```

To use result in another scope, you can make "result" as a global variable. As I can see you have commented out

```
//static public double results;
```

first un-comment it and remove var from

```
var results = columnQuery.ToList();
```

Hope this helps.